# Execute commands in JQuery using url address bar

Tags: jquery, url, command

I saw someone in a previous thread do something like this:

```
javascript: $('#answer-7061924 a.vote-up-off').click();
```

Found the thread: [How do end users (hackers) change Jquery and HTML values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061869/how-do-end-users-hackers-change-jquery-and-html-values)

I've tried performing the following (just to test):

```
javascript: $('a').click();
```

And it seemed to execute properly on Stack only. Is there a specific thing that this site has implemented in there html head, or is it something else?

Thanks!

Comment: any browser with developer tools and a console will let the user run arbitrary javascript on the page, accessing any variables available in the scope. ie Firebug for FireFox, the default dev tools for Chrome/WebKit, Opera, IE

Comment: jQuery would be required on the site.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Could I just modify the site's html and add the necessary links to the head then execute the commands?

Comment: @Derek I'm using Chrome but the code only seems to work on Stack. On any other site, nothing is executed.

Comment: you'll have to be specific. what site are you trying it on? what code are you trying to run? what output do you get in the console?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out! Sorry for the bust.